# Eigen cross product casting

Tags: c++, matrix, eigen

For `Eigen` the arguments of `.cross` must be known at compile-time to be of size 3. (For example declaring matrices as `Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1> ...`

Now I was wondering if casting a dynamic matrix would hurt? For example:

```
Eigen::Matrix<float, -1, 1> a(3), b(3), c(3);
...
typedef Eigen::Matrix<float, 3, 1> vector3_t;
c = ((vector3_t)a).cross((vector3_t)b);
```

---

I can't really see a down-side of this. Is there maybe a hidden copy mechanism involved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution will likely result in a copy, but since the operations themselves are all inlined and pretty simple, it might get optimized away almost completely (only way to be sure is to have a look at the assembly generated by your compiler).

To avoid the copy, you can try

```
typedef Eigen::Ref<const vector3_t> vector3_cr;
c = vector3_cr(a).cross(vector3_cr(b));
```

But is there a downside of declaring `a`, `b`, `c` as `vector3_t` from the beginning, in your case?

Comment: @MarcGlisse Afaik, it does not re-allocate `c` if it already has the correct size (I'm too lazy to investigate, though). You can verify (or disprove) that with [EIGEN_RUNTIME_NO_MALLOC](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPreprocessorDirectives.html)

Comment: Wrapping `c.data()` in `Eigen::Map<vector3_t>` avoids all the code that checks the size of `c`. Is that doable with a Ref instead?

Comment: You are right that it does not reallocate if c has size 3, it does if c has size 4 though... Depends what the user is looking for.

Comment: @MarcGlisse I can't respond to your questions, if you delete your questions afterwards. Instead of `Map<vector3_t>(c.data())` I'd rather write `c.head<3>() = ...` -- this will make sure that `c` is not smaller than 3. And if you want to assert that it was 3 already, use `Eigen::Ref<vector3_t>(c) = ...`

Comment: I only removed the first question (before you replied) because I noticed it was wrong and wanted to save you the time to answer it... `Eigen::Ref<vector3_t>(c)=...` does not compile for me, I have to put parentheses around it for some reason... `(Eigen::Ref<vector3_t>(c))=...` :-( `c.head<3>()` is perfect!

Comment: I guess the extra set of parentheses is necessary, because C++ will interpret it as equivalent to `Eigen::Ref<vector3_t> c = ...`, otherwise. I did not check before posting that.